# jQuery - Trigger Click Inside a Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have a page that will popup a [fancybox](http://fancybox.net) using

```
$('#showpopup').fancybox().trigger('click');
```

This may be triggered to popup several times (not at once) as the user navigates the page.

On the popup there is a button which triggers an action when clicked

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){

   $('#otherbutton').trigger('click');

});
```

When the fancybox popup shows first time I click #mybutton and #otherbutton will trigger once.

When the fancybox popup shows the second time I click #mybutton and #otherbutton will trigger twice.

When the fancybox popup shows the third time I click #mybutton and #otherbutton will trigger three times...and so on.

How can I stop this issue with fancybox so that otherbutton will only trigger once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are binding the `click` event handler for the `#mybutton` element within a Fancybox event (`onStart`, `onComplete`, etc.).

Two ways to fix this are:

1. On the `onClosed` or `onCleanup` events you can unbind the `click` event handler for the `#mybutton` element: `$('#mybutton').unbind('click');`. This way they will not build up and fire multiple times on a single click.
2. You can move `$('#mybutton').click(function(){$('#otherbutton').trigger('click');});` outside any Fancybox event handler (if the button is not present in the DOM until the Fancybox is displayed then you can use `.delegate()` to bind the `click` event handler to this button). `$(document).delegate('#mybutton', 'click', function () {...})` (note that you can change `document` to any root element that is present in the DOM at the time of binding).

Docs:

- `.unbind()`: http://api.jquery.com/unbind
- `.delegate`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

I also noticed that you linked to the old version of Fancybox, if you are using 1.x then I suggest changing to 2.0: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/